Почему в русском языке слово "мисинформация" не так широко употребляется, как слово "дезинформация"?
В английском языке есть разница между понятиями disinformation и misinformation. Под словом disinformation понимается намеренное распространение недостоверной информации, тогда как под словом misinformation понимается ложная информация, которая распространяется независимо от намерения ввести в заблуждение, но часто из-за случайности.

У слова дезинформация нет короткого русского аналога. Намеренно отправленные ложные сведения таким назвать вряд ли получится. А вот у миссинформации такой аналог есть, ошибочная информация или просто ошибка.

Фирма уведомляет о том, что в журнале «Вестник государственной
регистрации» в № 44 (300) от 10.11.2010г. и в № 49 (305) от
15.12.2010г. была допущена ошибка...

Да слово ошибка, имеет более широкое значение, чем предложенное вами миссинформация, но мне сложно представить контекст при котором это имело бы значение
